# How to integrate facebook with spring framework using spring boot and mongorepositry using mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-social-facebook, mongorepository

Hai i am new to mongodb database, i want to integrate facebook using spring-social,spring-boot, for mongodb database with mongo repository implementation,
 help me on this please.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the [*Accessing Facebook Data Guide*](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/) to get an idea regarding `spring-social` and check the *[Accessing Data with MongoDB](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/)* guide regarding `MongoDB`.